# how to include a UITableViewCell in another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview which contains a UITableViewCell and everything works fine. However I need to take this same UITableViewCell and display it in another ViewController. Is this possible in iOS?

Coming from an Android background, this can easily be done with an include tag. How can it be done in iOS?

Comment: A table view cell class can be used in any table view you want.

Comment: You can create custom UITableViewCell XIB with class and used anywhere in application.

Comment: The answer by @glaphi seems to answer your question but I'd like to know why you needed to add a `UITableViewCell` in to a non-tableView?

Comment: I will suggest to sub class an `UIView` to wrap the components. You can reuse the custom UIView to meet your need.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to take the cell instance and display it in another view controller. The short answer is yes, we can do that.

`UITableViewCell` is essentially a UIView so there is no reason why it can't be added as a subview outside of in `UITableView`. It is definitely an overkill since you could achieve the same result by designing a custom `UIView` where you can display the data as it was displayed in your `UITableViewCell`.

Here is a very basic example of how this can be done. 
In this example we take the selected cell with the data and then present a copy that we create of it in our new ViewController.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    private let myArray: [String] = ["First","Second","Third"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = OtherViewController()
        vc.cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.copyView() 
            // notice the .copyView() which makes the copy of that cell
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(myArray[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
}

class OtherViewController: UIViewController {

    var cell: UITableViewCell! {
        didSet {
            // positioning the cell
            cell.frame.origin.y = 100 // magic number  - remove
            view.addSubview(cell)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }

}


//MARK: - UIView Extensions (to make the copy of the cell)

extension UIView {
    func copyView<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)) as! T
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. A view can only have one superview. Stealing a reusable cell for a table view in one view controller and showing that view in another view controllers is just going to cause problems and not work as expected.

Comment: @rmaddy 1, The answer doesn't suggest it as a good solution rather possible. 2, There is no `stealing`, a copy of the cell is passed, take a look at `copyView()`. 3 The answer suggests a better solution: "It is definitely an overkill since you could achieve the same result by designing a custom UIView where you can display the data as it was displayed in your UITableViewCell".

Comment: @rmaddy I am not stealing a reusable cell. Please read my answer and comments.

Comment: @Glaphi Sorry. I didn't notice the use of `copyView` when I commented. That certainly helps. But I still don't think this is what the OP was asking for. But the question is really vague and can't be properly answered until it is clarified.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,it is possible to reuse it. You can use custom cell anywhere in your application